# Index/Match formula: Differentiating rows with same values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in sheet 1 which consists of customer referral dates, names, and referral statuses:

[image: Sheet1]

I then have another table in sheet 2 showing the 5 oldest customer referrals which are still open:

[image: Sheet 2]

The date column works fine. However, I'm running into problems when one or more customers have the same referral date. When matching the customer's name with their referral date, Excel always goes for the first result. As you can see in the oldest referrals table, customer "B" appears twice when it should actually be "B" & "C".

Here's the formulas I'm using:

To grab the dates: `=SMALL(IF(Sheet1!C:C="Open", Sheet1!A:A),1)`

To match the dates with a name: `=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!B3=Sheet1!A:A)*(Sheet1!C:C="Open"),0))`

Could anybody suggest a solution please?

Comment: Create another column from A and B in the first sheet. E.g. insert a column and in A2 put =B2&"_"&C2. Then use that new column for your matching.

Comment: @zsalya Wouldn't it always pick out 01/01/2018_B though?

Comment: Ah, I should have filled out by saying extend the input as well - so matching 01/01/2018_A will pass 01/01/2018_B and go on until it finds 01/01/2018_A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data on `Sheet1` are always sorted in date order then the formula below will yield the correct name:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$8,MATCH(Sheet2!B3&"Open",Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8&Sheet1!$C$2:$C$8,0)-1+COUNTIF($B$3:B3,B3))
```

(this assumes that the dates are in column **B** of `Sheet2`)

the formula will have to be entered as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) if you don't have dynamic arrays

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I have a third status for cases on hold. How would I go about changing B3&"Open" to include 'On Hold' as well? {"Open", "On Hold"} gives spill

Comment: Since you _do_ have dynamic arrays, `FILTER()` is the simples solution: `=INDEX(LET(dat,FILTER(Sheet1!A2:C8,Sheet1!C2:C8<>"Closed"),SORT(dat,1,1)),SEQUENCE(5),SEQUENCE(,3))` - the `SEQUENCE(5)` is because you're tracking the top 5, and the `SEQUENCE(3)` is because you have 3 columns in your data (date, name & status)